# Nuance of sentence when とも言えないが is used

Tags: meaning, particle-が

I have the following sentence, where I get the main meaning.

大学生とはいえ、あまりアルコールに強くない僕としては、ビール一杯の「やけざけ」（とも言えないが）で大分ハイな気分だったのだ。

"(Though) I am a student, I can't take much alcohol because I get high even from one beer as in binge-drinking."

but what is the role of とも言えないが?
So far, I think I understand ...とも言えない as "I am not really sure about ..." or " ...? I can't even say".

But what is the meaning of this phrase with this particle が ? Does it act as "but"? "But I can't even say (that)?" Obviously, the speaker knows that he gets high from a single beer. So why adding the uncertainty?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I think you got the general gist of the sentence. But, you translate:

> ビール一杯の「やけざけ」

as

> one beer as in binge-drinking

I'm not sure why you said that, but the の just acts in its normal fashion. I think you should consider it as something like

> one beer of binge-drinking

Then the parenthetical comment of とも言えないが can be understood as something like

> Well it can't really be called binge-drinking but...

Here the が acts like `but` and the thing that is `言えない` is calling what he does binge-drinking.